# How get additional fields in many-to-many relationships? yii2

Tags: yii2, many-to-many, relationships

Help me pls.

I have tables:

**goods** with fields:

> 1. *id*    int(11)
> 2. *name*    varchar(255)

**orders** with fields:

> 1. *id*    int(11)
> 2. *status_id*    int(2)

**orders_goods** with fields:

> 1. *id*    int(11)
> 2. *order_id*    int(11)
> 3. *good_id*        int(11)
> 4. *amount*        int(5)

I want to receive all the goods of the order by the *good_id* and an additional field *amount* from same line. After that, in the View, I want to display all order goods in this format:

> - *good.name* (*amount*)
> - *good.name* (*amount*)
> - *good.name* (*amount*)

Now in the **Orders** model I have a method to receive goods of order:

```
    public function getGoods()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Goods::className(), ['id' => 'good_id'])->viaTable(
            'orders_goods', ['order_id' => 'id'],
            function($query) {
                return $query->select('*')->from('orders_goods')->where(["order_id" => $this->id]);
            }
        );
    }
```

And in GridView I am displaying good names:

```
    [
            'label' => 'Goods',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                    return implode("\n", ArrayHelper::map($model->goods, 'id', 'name'));
            },
    ],
```

How can I add the amount of goods from the *amount* field to the display in the GridView? Can this be done without an additional intermediate model?

`"<pre>" . print_r($model->goods, true) . "</pre>"`

result:

```
<pre>
Array (
    [0] => app\models\Goods Object (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Monkey gold
        )
        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Monkey gold
        )
        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( )
        [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( )
        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] =>
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( )
        [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( )
        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( )
    )
    [1] => app\models\Goods Object (
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Monkey green
            )
            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Monkey green
            )
            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( )
            [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( )
            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] =>
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] =>
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( )
            [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( )
            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( )
        )
    )
</pre>
```

Comment: What is `$model->goods` value?

Comment: This is what the `getGoods()` function returns.

Comment: add result of `print_r($model->goods);`

Comment: add in question.. what print_r returns.

Comment: I did it. In question

Comment: You can create `hasMany()` relation in orders model with orders_goods.

Answer (score 0):

I asked if it was possible to do this without adding an intermediate model. Apparently this can not be done. As a result, I do this:

I added the model OrdersGoods, relation `hasMany()` in orders model:

```
public function getOrderGoods()
{
  return $this->hasMany(OrdersGoods::className(), ['order_id'=> 'id'])->select(['amount']);
}
```

In GridView:

```
[
    'label' => 'Goods',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        $goodsCount = count($model->goods);
        $resultValue = "";
        for($i=1; $i <= $goodsCount; $i++)
        {
            $resultValue .= "{$i}) {$model->goods[$i-1]->name} ({$model->orderGoods[$i-1]->amount})\n";
        }

        return $resultValue;
    },
],
```

Written not very well, but it works. Thank you!